# Create a list from a text file then retrieve the elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

Because I can't pass multiple arguments with `concurrent.futures` / `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

In this code : `pool.map(get_url, urls)`

I would like to pass the `iterations_file_numbers` variable directly into the generated urls variable in the `open_url_files()` function

I tried this way
`urls = [[line.strip(), iterations_file_number] for line in stream]`.

Python creates a list but when I do it in the `get_url()` function
`print(url[1])`
or
`print(url[:1])`
it prints me the whole list in full, I also tried `print(type(url))` and it tells me that this is a list.

The file simply contains a list of sites with line spaces.

The full code :

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import fileinput
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import traceback
from threading import Thread

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import warnings

from random import random
from queue import Queue



requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='bs4')

count_requests = 0
host_error = 0
iterations_file_number = 0

def get_url(url):
    global queue
    global queue_html
    global count_requests
    global host_error

    try:
        result_request = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=10)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result_request.text, 'html.parser')

        title = soup.title.get_text().splitlines(False)
        title = str(title)


        count_requests = count_requests + 1

        queue.put(f'{url} - {title} \n')


    except:
        queue.put(f'FAILED : {url} \n')
        host_error = host_error + 1


def file_writer(filepath, queue):
    global count_requests
    with open(filepath, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        while True:
            # get a line of text from the queue
            line = queue.get()
            if line is None:
                break
            # write it to file
            file.write(line)
            file.flush()
            queue.task_done()
    queue.task_done()




# create the shared queue
queue = Queue()
queue_html = Queue()
# defile the shared file path
filepath = '1_output_titles.txt'
filepath_html = '1_output_html.txt'

writer_thread = Thread(target=file_writer, args=(filepath,queue), daemon=True)
writer_thread.start()



queue.join()

def open_url_files():
    global urls
    global total_number_of_lines
    global iterations_file_number

    iterations_file_number = iterations_file_number + 1

    url_file = open(str(iterations_file_number) + ".txt", "r")
    url_file = url_file.readlines()
    total_number_of_lines = len(url_file)

    with open(str(iterations_file_number) + ".txt") as stream:
        urls = [line.strip() for line in stream]
        threadpool()

def threadpool():
    global urls
    global iterations_file_number
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500) as pool:
        pool.map(get_url, urls)
    open_url_files()

open_url_files()
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] that illustrates the problem — we don't want to see your full code because it contains many things that are completely unrelated to the issue.

Comment: I will simplify the code and update

Comment: You don't seem to have understood my previous comment. All that is needed here is a list variable create from a text file containing multiple elements that are to be accessed individually in a worker thread but can't be (or something along those line).